# Using formular in ui-view angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using a SinglePage-Application with one controller and three ui-view templates inside.
Here the HTML:

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-controller="gameController">     
    <div ui-view="viewUser"></div>
    <div ui-view="viewTeam"></div>
    <div ui-view="viewGame"></div>
</div>
```

Here the Config:

```
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("");

    $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
            url: "",
            controller: 'gameController',
            views: {
                "viewUser": { templateUrl: "templates/user-template.html" },
                "viewTeam": { templateUrl: "templates/team-template.html" },
                "viewGame": { templateUrl: "templates/game-template.html" }
            }
     });
}
```

Each view contains a formular with a ng-submit-event, and when i want to submit, $scope.formName is undefined. How i can use "$scope.teamName.$valid" inside ui-view?
Glad for any reply.

Comment: a <form name ="userForm">...</form> HTML Element
its inside 
<code>
    <div ui-view="userView">
    <form name ="userForm">...</form>
    </div>
</code>

Answer (score 0):

if i check in gameController $scope.on('$viewContentLoaded',.. and look in event.targetScope for userForm or teamForm or gameForm i found objectHTMLFormElement but when i try to add new user than $scope.userForm is undefined in function $scope.addUser(){...} witch is defined in gameController.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', 
    function(event, viewConfig){ 
        console.log('#c : ---------------------------- ');
        for(var e in event.targetScope){
            if(e.match(/^(userForm|teamForm|gameForm)$/)){
            console.log('#E : '+e)
            }
        }
    }
);
```